# Python unittest: to mock.patch() or just replace method with Mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, decorator

When mocking classes or methods when writing unittests in Python, why do I need to use [@patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#mock.patch) decorator? I just could replace the method with Mock object without any patch annotation.

Examples:

```
class TestFoobar(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.foobar = FooBar()

# 1) With patch decorator:

@patch.object(FooBar, "_get_bar")
@patch.object(FooBar, "_get_foo")
def test_get_foobar_with_patch(self, mock_get_foo, mock_get_bar):
    mock_get_bar.return_value = "bar1"
    mock_get_foo.return_value = "foo1"

    actual = self.foobar.get_foobar()

    self.assertEqual("foo1bar1", actual)

# 2) Just replacing the real methods with Mock with proper return_value:

def test_get_foobar_with_replacement(self):
    self.foobar._get_foo = Mock(return_value="foo2")
    self.foobar._get_bar = Mock(return_value="bar2")

    actual = self.foobar.get_foobar()

    self.assertEqual("foo2bar2", actual)
```

**Could someone produce an example, where patch decorator is good and replacing is bad?**

We have always used patch decorator with our team, but after reading [this comment](http://mauveweb.co.uk/posts/2014/09/every-mock-patch-is-a-little-smell.html#comment-1573595883) for a post, I got the idea that maybe we could write nicer-looking code without the need of patch decorators.

I understand that patching is temporary, so maybe with some cases, it is dangerous to not use patch decorator and replace methods with mock instead? Could it be that replacing objects in one test method can affect the result of the next test method?

I tried to prove this, but came up empty: both tests pass in the next code:

```
def test_get_foobar_with_replacement(self):
    self.foobar._get_foo = Mock(return_value="foo2")
    self.foobar._get_bar = Mock(return_value="bar2")

    actual = self.foobar.get_foobar()

    self.assertIsInstance(self.foobar._get_bar, Mock)
    self.assertIsInstance(self.foobar._get_foo, Mock)
    self.assertEqual("foo2bar2", actual)

def test_get_foobar_with_real_methods(self):

    actual = self.foobar.get_foobar()

    self.assertNotIsInstance(self.foobar._get_bar, Mock)
    self.assertNotIsInstance(self.foobar._get_foo, Mock)
    self.assertIsInstance(self.foobar._get_bar, types.MethodType)
    self.assertIsInstance(self.foobar._get_foo, types.MethodType)
    self.assertEqual("foobar", actual)
```

Full source code (Python 3.3): dropbox.com/s/t8bewsdaalzrgke/test_foobar.py?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`patch.object` will restore the item you patched to its original state after the test method returns. If you monkey-patch the object yourself, you need to restore the original value if that object will be used in another test.

In your two examples, you are actually patching two different things. Your call to `patch.object` patches the *class* `FooBar`, while your monkey patch patches a specific *instance* of `FooBar`.

Restoring the original object isn't important if the object will be created from scratch each time. (You don't show it, but I assume `self.foobar` is being created in a `setUp` method, so that even though you replace its `_get_foo` method, you aren't reusing that *specific* object in multiple tests.)

Comment: I thought I only patched the method, not the class. I read [this](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object) and as I understood, I patched the method, not the class. Could you show me how to do it better?

Comment: "Restoring the original object isn't important if the object will be created from scratch each time" - I understand that this means it is ok to just replace the method with Mock() and not use patching as long as you create the reusable objects in the setUp method. I made an example where the second test gets assertion error - the test expects the method not to be an instance of Mock, but it is, because the foobar object was created outside the test class, not in the setUp method: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1djmm9bv7op25q/test_foobar2.py?dl=0